# ¿Existe método para cambiar el tamaño de pagina A4 a Carta con html2pdf de itext? No lo encuentro

Tags: java, itext, html2pdf

Estoy trabajando en java con la herramienta de itext7, especificamente  html2pdf para generar pdf a partir de un jEditorPane que contiene texto en formato html. Me genera el pdf sin problemas pero en tamaño A4 y no encuentro método alguno para cambiar el tamaño a Carta. ¿Alguien ha podido cambiar el tamaño a4 a carta?

```
PdfWriter w = new PdfWriter("ejemplo.pdf");
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(String.valueOf(JeditorPane.getText()), w);
```

Comment: ¿Para el pdfwriter importas esto import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;?

Comment: no estimado, el importe que tengo es este: import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;  cuando realizé el importe que tu mencionaste arriba me dice que ese paquete no existe.

Comment: No tengo a la mano una forma de probar el cambio del tamaño de pagina pero esto te servirá https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext5-building-blocks/page-size

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, pero el tema es que el texto lo tengo el formato html, entonces si uso la forma en que me planteas para generar pdf, me genera el pdf en tamaño carta pero con los tags de html, entonces no me sirve, la herramienta que sí me sirve y me genera pdf sin tags html es html2pdf, pero sólo me genera pdf en tamaño a4! Saludos y gracias por ayudar (pd: esoty usando itext 7)

Comment: La única forma que veo de cambiar el tamaño de tu pdfwriter es con el document creando un new rectangle. Trata de buscar como instanciar tu pdfwriter con un document para que no te de problemas.

Comment: `Document document = new Document(PageSize.Letter, left, right, top, bottom);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));`

Answer (score 0):

El valor equivalente a tamaño de página "carta", lo puedes definir en el constructor de Html2Pdf. Este valor debe ser 'ANSI_A'. En la documentación que ofrece el sitio web de Html2Pdf se ofrece un enlace con todos los tamaños permitidos, que por cierto, son muchísimos.